# ES6 proxied class, access private property (Cannot read private member #hidden from an object whose class did not declare it)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, properties, private, es6-proxy

Im playing around with proxy objects, classess and private properties.
And came across this error message:

```
/home/marc/projects/playground/pipeline/clsss.js:14
        this.#hidden = !this.#hidden;
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read private member #hidden from an object whose class did not declare it
    at Proxy.toggle (/home/marc/projects/playground/pipeline/clsss.js:14:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marc/projects/playground/pipeline/clsss.js:37:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Code to reproduce:

```js
class Parent {

    #hidden;

    constructor() {
        this.#hidden = false;
    }

    get hidden() {
        return this.#hidden;
    }

    toggle() {
        this.#hidden = !this.#hidden;
        console.log("Changed", this.#hidden)
        return this.#hidden;
    }

}


const p = new Parent();
const proxy = new Proxy(p, {
    get: (target, prop, receiver) => {
        return target[prop];
    }
});

console.log(p.toggle())
console.log(proxy.toggle())  // this is the problem
console.log(p.toggle())
```

Is there a way to handle private properties on proxied class instance?

Why does this not work with a proxy?

Thanks for any hint/answer.

Edit: found a related issue on github: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/issues/106
A quick hack i discoverd is to use:

```js
const proxy = new Proxy(..., {
    get: (target, prop, receiver) => {

        // bind context to original object
        if (target[prop] instanceof Function) {
            return target[prop].bind(p);
        }

        return target[prop];

    }
});
```

But this seems very unclean/wrong.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the motivation for using a Proxy? Maybe there is an alternative.

Comment: This is why private fields are a bad idea.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Sorry for the long break til my answer: I want to "merge" to objects together. 2 Seperate objects, with diffrent methods/properties should be accessable through one as "fallback". It property `x` does not exists on obj1, try obj2. For that the proxy should work "transparent". I think i use the check with `... instanceof Function`/`.bind(...)`

Comment: Please don't [add answers to questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question).

Answer (score 5):

You can bind the method on the constructor if this is the desired behavior:

```
constructor() {
      this.#hidden = false;
      this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
class Parent {

    #hidden;

    constructor() {
        this.#hidden = false;
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    get hidden() {
        return this.#hidden;
    }

    toggle() {
        this.#hidden = !this.#hidden;
        console.log("Changed", this.#hidden)
        return this.#hidden;
    }

}


const p = new Parent();
const proxy = new Proxy(p, {
    get: (target, prop, receiver) => {
        return target[prop];
    }
});

console.log(p.toggle())
console.log(proxy.toggle())  // this is the problem
console.log(p.toggle())
```

Otherwise you can proxy the class itself:

```js
class Parent {

    #hidden;

    constructor() {
        this.#hidden = false;
    }

    get hidden() {
        return this.#hidden;
    }

    toggle() {
        this.#hidden = !this.#hidden;
        //console.log("Changed", this.#hidden)
        return this.#hidden;
    }

}


const p = new Parent();
const ParentProxy = new Proxy(Parent, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        return target[prop];
    }
});

const p2 = new ParentProxy();

console.log('p toggle:', p.toggle());
console.log('p2 toggle:', p2.toggle());  //
//console.log(proxy.toggle())  // this is the problem
console.log('p toggle:', p.toggle());
console.log('p2 toggle:', p2.toggle());
```

Comment: "*Note: you must use `newTarget` of `handler.construct`*" - OP doesn't use the `construct` trap at all? This works fine. In your example, your handler does nothing but dispatch to `Reflect.construct` with the exact same arguments, which as the same as not trapping `construct` at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, read the error message it says `Cannot read private member #hidden from an object whose class did not declare it` once you made a proxy and trying to access something from it won't have the same class as the original that you are wrapping.

Update: You can read more about private fields and how they work here https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: But the proxy returns 1:1 the object instance, the context of `this` has not changed and any lookup/access on the proxy obcjet is striaght forwared to the original instance.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to access the private instance from the proxy, and not from the inside of the class. 
`get: () => { // here we are accessing from the proxy not from the class itself}` so it is expected behaviour

Comment: Makes sense, but why can i log the property `console.log(p.hidden, proxy.hidden)`? This works... I expected that this fails too.

Comment: Well because you are calling public getter `get hidden` that is not private. I am sure that you will get an error if you try `console.log(p.#hidden)`

Comment: Thats correct, but `toggle()` is also not private

Comment: Yep and that is expected too. toggle is not private, but the variable is accessed inside the toggle call so the class is accessing its private field.

Comment: If that solves your concern, please mark the answer as a solution. 
You can read more about the private field here https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: No. This does not answer my question. The question is how to use private propertys & proxies.In your link not a single word about proxies nor that this does not work. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `Proxy` object gives a direct access to the `target` and `prop` so you can simply access the privates as if you are directly accessing from the instance.

My approach would be like;

```js
class Parent {

    #hidden;

    constructor() {
        this.#hidden = false;
    }

    get hidden() {
        return this.#hidden;
    }

    toggle() {
        this.#hidden = !this.#hidden;
        console.log("Changed", this.#hidden)
        return this.#hidden;
    }

}


var p = new Parent();
var proxy = new Proxy(p,{get: (target,prop,receiver) => _ => target[prop]()});
console.log(p.toggle())
console.log(proxy.toggle())  // this is the problem
console.log(p.toggle())
```

On a second level of thinkering, this in fact might become better such as;

```js
class Parent {
    #hidden;

    constructor() {
        this.#hidden = false;
    }

    get hidden() {
        return this.#hidden;
    }

    toggle() {
        this.#hidden = !this.#hidden;
        console.log("Changed", this.#hidden)
        return this.#hidden;
    }

}


var p = new Parent();
var proxy = new Proxy(p,{get: (target,prop,receiver) => target[prop].bind(target)});
console.log(p.toggle())
console.log(proxy.toggle())  // this is the problem
console.log(p.toggle());
```

which clearly tells you that the `Proxy` object is **not** the instance itself. You should explicitly `bind` the passed function properties (or prototype methods) which have access to the "*private*" properties of the `Class` to `target` in order to make them function properly.

Comment: @Bergi. Yeah but that's no big deal. It can simply work when we apply a function test to `target[prop]`.

Comment: So please do that.