# Can a Proxy really provide access to private fields of a class?

Tags: javascript, private-members, es6-proxy

I'm reading the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#no_private_property_forwarding), and it seems to imply that even for private fields, it would be possible to access them via a Proxy. See the blurb that starts with "....To fix this....". But the example given, doesn't work. My code is shown below:

The class with the private field:

```
class Danger {
    #areYouSure = "magic";

    grave(){
        console.log("Yes, grave danger");
        return true;
    }

}

module.exports = Danger;
```

Trying to use a proxy to access it:

```
const Danger = require('./testing-private');

const handler = {
    get(target, property, receiver){
        return target[property];
    }
};
const dangerProxy = new Proxy(new Danger(), handler);

console.log("--------------------------------------", dangerProxy.areYouSure);
```

This prints out:

```
-------------------------------------- undefined
```

If I replace "dangerProxy.areYouSure" with "dangerProxy.#areYouSure". I get

```
/home/zaphod/code/math/js-experiments/src/danger-proxy.js:29
console.log("--------------------------------------", dangerProxy.#areYouSure);
                                                                 ^

SyntaxError: Private field '#areYouSure' must be declared in an enclosing class
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Is there a way to get this working or are my expectations incorrect?

Comment: Note that the example in the docs is showing how to proxy to a method that _uses_ a private field, not to the field itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 proxied class, access private property (Cannot read private member #hidden from an object whose class did not declare it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416881/es6-proxied-class-access-private-property-cannot-read-private-member-hidden-f)

Comment: @jeremy-denis - thanks for the pointer. That linked to question did indirectly answer my question though TJ Crowder answered that more directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section of the documentation is really about `this` within a getter property (though it's not very clear about that), not about private properties per se. It's just that the value of `this` within the getter matters more when the getter is accessing a private field.

Suppose we do the same thing using a pseudo-private property (private only by convention):

```js
class Secret {
    _secret;
    constructor(secret) {
        this._secret = secret;
    }
    get secret() {
        return this._secret.replace(/\d+/, "[REDACTED]");
    }
}

const aSecret = new Secret("123456");
console.log(aSecret.secret); // [REDACTED]
// Looks like a no-op forwarding...
const proxy = new Proxy(aSecret, {});
console.log(proxy.secret); // [REDACTED]
```

As you can see, that works. But **why** does it work when a true private field didn't? Because of the value of `this` during the getter call. Let's see what `this` is:

```js
class Secret {
    _secret;
    constructor(secret) {
        this._secret = secret;
    }
    get secret() {
        console.log(`this === aSecret? ${this === aSecret}`);
        console.log(`this === proxy? ${this === proxy}`);
        return this._secret.replace(/\d+/, "[REDACTED]");
    }
}

const aSecret = new Secret("123456");
const proxy = new Proxy(aSecret, {}); // (Had to move this, but it doesn't change anything important)
console.log(aSecret.secret); // [REDACTED]
console.log(proxy.secret); // [REDACTED]
```

When we use `aSecret` directly, `this` is (perhaps obviously) `aSecret`:

```
this === aSecret? true
this === proxy? false
[REDACTED]
```

...but when we go through the proxy, `this` is the proxy:

```
this === aSecret? false
this === proxy? true
[REDACTED]
```

That's because the default implementation of the `get` trap effectively looks like this:

```
get(target, propName, receiver) {
    return Reflect.get(target, propName, receiver);
}
```

In `proxy.secret`, `target` will be `aSecret`, `propName` will be `"secret"`, and `receiver` will be `proxy`. [`Reflect.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) will call the getter function using `receiver` (the proxy) as `this`, because that's what the third argument is for, the value of `this` during the operation. `this` being `proxy` instead of `aSecret` during the operation doesn't matter for our pseudo-private example, because when the getter method tries to access `this._secret`, it accesses it on the proxy, which then gets it from the target. But that won't work with a truly private field, because the proxy object doesn't have the private field.

The solution they provide is to change the `get` trap from the default above to:

```
get(target, propName, receiver) {
    return target[propName];
    // The above is like `return Reflect.get(target, propName, target);`
    // Note `target` instead of `receiver` for third argument −^
}
```

That way, `this` in the getter method is `target` (`aSecret`), not `receiver` (`proxy`), and so accessing the private field works.

> Can a Proxy really provide access to private fields of a class?

A Proxy can't expose the private fields of an instance that doesn't already provide a non-private way of accessing them, no. But it can provide access to getters and methods that have access to those fields. But you have to provide the right `this`.