# Cannot access puppeteer Proxy in my Jest test (TypeError: Cannot read private member #frameManager from an object whose class did not declare it)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer, javascript-proxy

What could be the reason of me not being able to access the Proxy of the `CustomPage` class in my test file? I get this error...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1iey.png)

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

class CustomPage {
  static async build() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const customPage = new CustomPage(page);
    return new Proxy(customPage, {
      get: function (target, property) {
        return customPage[property] || browser[property] || page[property];
      },
    });
  }
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }
  getContentsOf(selector) {
    return this.page.$eval(selector,el=>el.innerHTML);
  }
}

module.exports = CustomPage;
```

```
const Page = require("./helpers/page");

let page;

beforeEach( async () => {
    page = await Page.build();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:5002');
});
afterEach(async () => {
  await page.close();
});
describe("we started HomePage tests and...",() => {
  test("can see blog create form", async () => {
    const subscribeButton = await page.$eval(".subscribe-btn",el=>el.innerHTML);
    expect(subscribeButton).toEqual("გამოწერა");
  });
});
```

I don't know what exactly should I try to fix it.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). That full TypeError message is important info that should be searchable. See [Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757867/cannot-read-private-member-from-an-object-whose-class-did-not-declare-it). That said, proxies are confusing and so I wouldn't suggest doing this trick. I'd just write a normal [POM](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom) so it's readable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 proxied class, access private property (Cannot read private member #hidden from an object whose class did not declare it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416881/es6-proxied-class-access-private-property-cannot-read-private-member-hidden-f)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with binding, as described in [ES6 proxied class, access private property (Cannot read private member #hidden from an object whose class did not declare it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416881/es6-proxied-class-access-private-property-cannot-read-private-member-hidden-f). Proxy `get` should return a function that's bound to the instance you want to call it on:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.2.0

class CustomPage {
  static async build() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const customPage = new CustomPage(page);
    const targets = [customPage, browser, page];
    return new Proxy(customPage, {
      get: (target, property) => {
        for (const t of targets) {
          if (t[property] === undefined) {
            continue;
          }
          else if (typeof t[property] === "function") {
            return t[property].bind(t);
          }

          return t[property];
        }
      }
    });
  }

  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  getContentsOf(selector) {
    return this.page.$eval(selector, el => el.innerHTML);
  }
}

let page;
(async () => {
  page = await CustomPage.build();
  await page.setContent("<p>hello world</p>");
  console.log(await page.getContentsOf("p")); // => hello world
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => page?.close());
```

That said, red flags should be raised here--this is much too complicated and prone to confusing errors like the one you're already battling. Best case scenario, as a client of `CustomPage`, if I call a function, I have no idea which instance is receiving the call. `page.close()` becomes impossible to call because `browser.close()` is called instead. Even if the intended behavior occurs, the code will still be difficult to read.

If you want to write an abstraction on the browser and/or page, don't do it prematurely. Wait until you have a need for it. If you do, try for something like a [page object model](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom) from Playwright. In a POM, you don't expose `page` or `browser` to the caller at all, enforcing all test actions occur on a higher level based on the specific set of actions and elements for a page. This ensures your tests are written at a consistent level of abstraction, as the caller is unable to access lower-level `page` and `browser` functions unless the POM has explicitly exposed them.